# Converting String to Time using SimpleDateFormat issues

Tags: android, simpledateformat

So, I'm using SimpleDateFormat to convert a String which is "HH:MM AA" to "HH:MM",
The problem is my code works fine on eclipse but when I run this on Android Studio it shows wrong output. Here are my both codes.

[image: Eclipse code]

[image: Android Studio code]

Comment: Android isn't Java. The SDK's are different. So yes, you will get different results

Comment: Can you please tell me how to solve this or get the right output on android studio?

Comment: The code in your two screenshots is not identical. As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Please post your code as text in the question. Screen shots may be a nice supplement, but text is easier to read and also invites readers to copy and run it should we desire. Which will in the end help yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion from 12 hours time to 24 hours time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531632/conversion-from-12-hours-time-to-24-hours-time-in-java)

Comment: I had that problem figured out. But I'm now facing some other problem, I actually wanted to make an alarm app. Now time I'm trying to ring the alarm is on hh:mm format. But in the alarm manager it doesn't take hh:mm to check, rather it takes time on milliseconds. But when I convert that to on milliseconds its not as long as system time in milliseconds.as system counts year , month and date to while calculating to milli seconds. is there any way to make system count only hh:mm format while checking systems current time for alarm to ring? sorry for the long description. I'm new to this.

Comment: alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeinmillisecond,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);           The thing that I am wanting to know is that here can I somehow use hh:mm format to set the alarm instead of calculating time in millisecond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using "MM" as minutes but it should be "mm". "MM" is for months.

The part "HH" is fine when you want the 24 hour values back.

try soemthing like this:

```
public static String getTimeFormatted(String time){
    String s = "";
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.US);
        Date d = sdf.parse(time);


        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.US);
        s = formatter.format(d);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        s = ex.getMessage();
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to give time as hh:mm format in alarm manager on android studio instead of  triggered after certain milliseconds?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
 String date="2:30 PM";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf5 = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf6 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    try {
        String str=sdf6.format(sdf5.parse(date));
        Log.d("DATE TO:",str);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: because you are passing In Upper latter in android and small in eclipes.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  public String changeDateFormatFromAnother(String date){
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
        String resultDate = "";
        try {
            resultDate=outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultDate;
    }
```

Comment: Is that supposed to convert "HH:MM AA" to "HH:MM"??!! One of us is going to be very surprised…

Comment: view convention of date and time https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: and change accordingly

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
    String newTimeString = LocalTime
            .parse("2:30 PM", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH))
            .toString();
    System.out.println(newTimeString);
```

This prints

> 14:30

Even on Android you should consider not fighting with the age-old and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is much nicer to work with. A `LocalTime` is a time of day without date and without time zone, so seems to match your requirements very neatly.

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

Yes, `java.time` works nicely on older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26, I’m told) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### What went wrong in your code?

- In your first screenshot, you are formatting using the format pattern
  string `HH:mm`. Uppercase `HH` for hour of day and lowercase `mm` for
  minute of hour. So you get the expected `14:30`.
- In your second screenshot you used `HH:MM`, that is, uppercase `MM`. This is for month. Since the string you parsed didn’t have a month in it, it defaulted to January, which in turn was rendered as `01` in your result, so you got `14:01`. It’s very typical for `SimpleDateFormat` that it agrees to print a month that was never there, just pretends that everything is fine, doesn’t inform you of an error. This is just one of the many reasons I recommend you avoid that class.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.