# SimpleDateFormat returns wrong time from Firestore Timestamp - why?

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, simpledateformat

When using SimpleDateFormat to produce a string from a Firebase Firestore Timestamp object, I get an incorrect/nonsense result. Why?

I fabricate some Timestamps and send them to Firestore. I see expected results in the Firebase/Firestore console. I then get the douments from Firestore, retrieve the Timestamps from the documents, and convert them first to Date objects then to strings using SimpleDateFormat. The last step produces incorrect strings: specifically times "18:08:00" instead of "18:28:53" and "19:08:64" instead of "19:28:53" (Note: seconds > 59)

Firebase console shows the timestamps I expect:

```
eventTimestamp August 10, 2019 at 6:28:53 PM UTC+1
collectedTimestamp August 10, 2019 at 7:28:53 PM UTC+1
```

But the following code shows the problem (selectedMedEvent is an object created from the document retrieved, and getEventTimestamp() and getCollectedTimestamp() both return Firebase Timestamp objects):

```
Date eDate = selectedMedEvent.getEventTimestamp().toDate();
Date cDate = selectedMedEvent.getCollectedTimestamp().toDate();
String eString = selectedMedEvent.getEventTimestamp().toString();
String cString = selectedMedEvent.getCollectedTimestamp().toString();

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
String eventDateString = formatter.format(eDate);
String collectedDateString = formatter.format(cDate);
Log.d(TAG, "Event Date is '" + eDate + "' or " + eString + " but SimpleDateFormat gives '" + eventDateString + "'");
Log.d(TAG, "Collected Date is '" + cDate + "' or " + cString + " but SimpleDateFormat gives '" + collectedDateString + "'");
```

Logcat shows the two Date objects printed as expected (matching the Firestore  console) but errors elsewhere:

```
Event Date is 'Sat Aug 10 18:28:53 GMT+01:00 2019' or Timestamp(seconds=1565458133, nanoseconds=0) but SimpleDateFormat gives '10/08/2019 18:08:00'
Collected Date is 'Sat Aug 10 19:28:53 GMT+01:00 2019' or Timestamp(seconds=1565461733, nanoseconds=648000000) but SimpleDateFormat gives '10/08/2019 19:08:64'
```

Note the non-zero nanoseconds. When I create the Timestamp the nanoseconds value is always 0.

What is this happening and how do I fix it?

Later: I have created a stand-alone routine that demonstrates the problem. I plugged in the seconds and nanoseconds values that the Logcat had given me and I get the same unexpected SimpleDateFormat strings. Code is:

```
private void showBug() {
    Timestamp ts1 = new Timestamp( 1565458133, 0);
    Timestamp ts2 = new Timestamp( 1565461733, 648000000);

    Date eDate = ts1.toDate();
    Date cDate = ts2.toDate();
    String eString = ts1.toString();
    String cString = ts2.toString();

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
    String eventDateString = formatter.format(eDate);
    String collectedDateString = formatter.format(cDate);
    Log.d(TAG, "Event Date is '" + eDate + "' or " + eString + " but SimpleDateFormat gives '" + eventDateString + "'");
    Log.d(TAG, "Collected Date is '" + cDate + "' or " + cString + " but SimpleDateFormat gives '" + collectedDateString + "'");
}
```

Logcat output is identical to previously reported.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Possible partial duplicate of [Converting String to Time using SimpleDateFormat issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449169/converting-string-to-time-using-simpledateformat-issues)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Your direct problem is wrong codes in your formatting pattern. Your larger problem is using terrible legacy classes.

Convert from Firestore [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) (not to be confused with [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Timestamp.html)) to modern [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = Instant.of( timestamp.getSeconds() , timestamp.getNanoseconds() )
```

Example: `Instant.of( 1_565_461_733L , 648_000_000L )`

Convert from [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to Firestore `Timestamp`.

```
new Timestamp( instant.getEpochSecond() , instant.getNano() )
```

**Beware of data loss:** Apparently [Firestore is limited to microseconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) rather than [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution. Why their own [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) class resolves to nanos is beyond my comprehension. (I do not use Firestore/Firebase.)

## Formatting pattern incorrect

> new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS");

You are using an incorrect formatting pattern. The pattern codes are case-sensitive. Read the class Javadoc, and search Stack Overflow as this has been covered [thousands of times already](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&source=hp&ei=qnpPXY2rHqr_0gLr7JeICA&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20SimpleDateFormat&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20SimpleDateFormat&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2637.10308..10899...0.0..1.129.3315.45j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......35i39j0j0i131.ezzXF-pXblU&ved=0ahUKEwiNqPCL4PnjAhWqv1QKHWv2BYEQ4dUDCAs&uact=5). **Search Stack Overflow before posting.**

And you should not be using that class anyways.

## *java.time*

The terrible date-time classes in Java such as `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date`, and `Timestamp` were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes. Both `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Timestamp` were replaced by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) (and by [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) work).

Unfortunately, it seems that Firestore has not yet been updated to *java.time*. Fortunately, you can convert to-and-fro between the legacy and modern classes. Look to new `to…` & `from…` methods found on the old classes.

### `java.time.Instant`

You seem to have inputs of a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, plus fractional second as a count of nanoseconds. Pass those to a factory method in `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond ( 1_565_461_733L , 648_000_000L );
```

> instant.toString(): 2019-08-10T18:28:53.648Z

### Truncating

Timestore is [limited to microseconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) rather than the nanoseconds in *java.time*. So you may want to make a habit of truncating for consistency.

```
instant = instant.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROS ) ;
```

### Firestore `Timestamp` class

Apparently Firestore has its own [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) class. It's constructor takes a `java.util.Date` object. So we *could* convert from `java.time.Instant` to `java.util.Date` and feed that to a Firebase `Timestamp`. Unfortunately, **`java.util.Date` is limited to milliseconds**, even less granular than the microseconds of the data type within Firestore. Converting to `Date` means data loss.

Construct a Firestore `Timestamp` using the other constructor method, where you pass a count of whole seconds plus nanos.

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp( instant.getEpochSecond() , instant.getNano() ) ;
```

When retrieving a Firestore `Timestamp`, immediately convert to `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.of( ts.getSeconds() , ts.getNanoseconds() ) ;
```

If you want to see that same moment adjusted from UTC to some time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

Notice that in none of the code above did we work in strings. So **no need for any formatting pattern**.

Learn to do all your business logic in *java.time*. Avoid the terrible `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Date objects in Java only have a resolution of milliseconds.  They can not store any unit of measurement smaller than that.  Firestore timestamps can store time units as small as nanoseconds, which is much much smaller than a millisecond.

So, if you convert a Date to a Firestore Timestamp object, the nanoseconds component will always be 0 because there are are simply no nanos available from the Date object.  0 is just the default in this case.

To put it more formally, converting a Timestamp to a Date is *narrowing* conversion, where you lose precision.  Converting a Date to a Timestamp is *widening* conversion, where new precision is added, and missing data set to zero by default.