# SimpleDateFormat is giving wrong hours and seconds data

Tags: java, datetime, time, format, simpledateformat

I'm using SimpleDateFormat to get the hours and seconds in this format "HH:MM a" for 2 dates in same function. The output printing is same for both of them and it is mostly of the first date. The code for it is as follows:

```
//to get the time
public static void getHourAndTime(Date startDate, Date endDate){
    
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM a");
    String formattedstartTime = formatter.format(startDate);
    System.out.println("startTime"+formattedstartTime);

    String formattedEndTime = formatter.format(endDate);
    System.out.println("endTime"+formattedEndTime);
}
```

Any solution/ reason for this would be helpful.

Edit: this was a piece of an old code in the application, that I was trying to change.

Thanks

Comment: MM is for the month. Use mm for minutes.

Comment: check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) about meaning of  `MM`, also having `HH` with `a` is wrong - BTW better stop using outdated classes like `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`. The *new* (Java 8, 2014!) classes from the `java.time` package are recommended instead

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: While this question doesn’t seem to be an exact duplicate, there are many related questions, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734452/display-current-time-in-12-hour-format-with-am-pm) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50449169/converting-string-to-time-using-simpledateformat-issues). Under those questions please see the answers that are using java.time and not the old `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks @user16320675, will keep in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` and its methods are obsolete and buggy.  Unless you must use Date I would use classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.  Here is how the change would look by modifying your code. Note the change from 24 hour clock `(HH)` to 12 hour clock `(hh)` as pointed out by @OleV.V.

```
getHourAndTime(LocalDateTime.now(), LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(600));
            

public static void getHourAndTime(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a");
    System.out.println("startTime: " + startDate.format(dtf));
    System.out.println("endTime: " + endDate.format(dtf));
}
```

prints

```
startTime: 11:53 AM
endTime: 12:03 PM
```