# converting between 12 hour time format to military time

Tags: java, converters

I am currently trying to write a method that takes a string like "1pm" and converts it to military time --> 13

Right now I have the following and it is not working correctly. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

/**
     * Set the hour of this appointment, using a more human-friendly
     * string.
     * @param newHour The new hour for this  appointment, using an
     *                am/pm designation such as "9am" or "5pm".
     */

```
public void setTime(String newHour)
{
    String day = newHour.substring(newHour.length() - 2);
    String dig = newHour.substring(2, newHour.length() - 2);

    if (dig.equals("12"))
    {
        dig = "0";
    }
    if (day.equals("am"))
    {
        hour = Integer.parseInt(dig);
    }
    else 
    {
        hour = Integer.parseInt(dig) + 12;
    }
}
```

Comment: `LocalTime.parse(newHour.toUpperCase(), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ha")).getHour()`

Comment: Hi Jane, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be sure to search for your problem on the site, if not on Google too, before asking. It happens that Stack Overflow already has several solutions to this problem, which would likely be quicker ways to get a solution :) e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531632/conversion-from-12-hours-time-to-24-hours-time-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion from 12 hours time to 24 hours time in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531632/conversion-from-12-hours-time-to-24-hours-time-in-java)

Comment: I’d use a DateTimeFormatte and LocalDate

Answer (score 0):

Your "dig" string is wrong. Its startindex should be 0.

```
String dig = newHour.substring(0, newHour.length() - 2);
```

Comment: how would this account for "12am" or midnight? I think i am missing that condition and I am not exactly sure how to write for it. Thanks so much

Comment: That already seems to be handled in your code. For "12am" the dig variable would be set to "0", and since it is am you would get 0. "12pm" would return "12".