# Convert 12-hour time formats to 24-hour formats

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to create a time conversion function that converts 12-hour time formats to 24-hour formats. My code works for all inputs except the following:
12:05:39AM.

I am having trouble understanding what I am doing wrong

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.joining;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

class Result {

    /*
     * Complete the 'timeConversion' function below.
     *
     * The function is expected to return a STRING.
     * The function accepts STRING s as parameter.
     */

    public static String timeConversion(String s) {
    // Write your code here
    
    if (s.substring(8).equals("PM")){
        String hour = s.substring(0,2);
        if (Integer.parseInt(hour) != 12){
            int newHour = (Integer.parseInt(hour) + 12) % 24;
            return (newHour + s.substring(2,8));
        }
        return (hour + s.substring(2,8));    
    }
    else if (s.substring(8).equals("AM")){
        String AMhour = s.substring(0,2);
        if (Integer.parseInt(AMhour) == 12){
            int newHour = ((Integer.parseInt(AMhour) + 12) % 24);
            return (newHour + s.substring(2,8));  
        }
        return  (AMhour + s.substring(2,8));
    }
    else {
        return("Not found"); 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "does not work" exactly means. Does the code produce a result you don't expect? Does the code throw an exception/error? When I'm testing your code with the value "12:05:39AM" it returns "0:05:39", which seems pretty correct to me.

Comment: Please use actual date parsing libraries

Comment: [The answer by Cloud here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37388524/5772882), doesn’t it give you most of what you want? You will want to add support for seconds yourself. Use format pattern letter `ss` for second of minute.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this segment:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(AMhour) == 12){
    int newHour = ((Integer.parseInt(AMhour) + 12) % 24);
    return (newHour + s.substring(2,8));
}
```

You're getting `0` in `newHour`, and when you're converting it into string, you're getting `0:mm:ss`.

To solve this, type of problem you can add an extra `0` in the front as this is a fixed case. Or, just do:

```
return String.format("%02d%s", newHour,  s.substring(2,8));
```

**NOTE: USE *java.time***

Please use actual java libraries to deal with these type of conversions. You could do the conversion with `java.time` by doing:

```
return LocalTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ssa", Locale.US))
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

I recommend you do it using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(timeConversion("12:05:39AM"));
    }

    public static String timeConversion(String s) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:m:sa", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(s, dtfInput);

        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        return time.format(dtfOutput);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
00:05:39
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/GKL6wu)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A simple example of Date and Time formatting:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String timePattern = "H:mm:ss SSS";
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePattern);
    
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    System.out.println("The date is: " +DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL).format(ldt));
    System.out.println("The time is: " + timeFormatter.format(ldt));
}
```

[Official JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)